# Https Connection with ask.wireshark.org not working

Tags: java

I'm trying to connect to a webpage with HTTPS protocol.
But its returning 403 response.
So how do I connect to HTTPS servers without checking for certificate.
I referred similar kind of code from StackOverflow. It works well for other pages but not with [wireshark](https://ask.wireshark.org/questions/634/acc-to-wireshark-999-of-my-outgoing-packets-have-a-bad-checksum).

```
package Others;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.security.GeneralSecurityException;
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.security.cert.CertificateException;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;
import javax.net.ssl.HostnameVerifier;
import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSession;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManager;
import javax.net.ssl.X509TrustManager;
import org.apache.http.conn.ssl.AllowAllHostnameVerifier;

public class wireshark {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        TrustManager[] trustAllCertificates = new TrustManager[] {
            new X509TrustManager() {

                public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    return null;
                }

            }
        };

        HostnameVerifier trustAllHostnames = new HostnameVerifier() {
            public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
                return true; // Just allow them all.
            }


        };

        try {
            URL url=new URL("https://ask.wireshark.org/questions/634/acc-to-wireshark-999-of-my-outgoing-packets-have-a-bad-checksum");
            System.setProperty("jsse.enableSNIExtension", "true");
            SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
            sc.init(null, trustAllCertificates, new SecureRandom());
            HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());
            HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(trustAllHostnames);

        //    HttpsURLConnection httpConnection=null ;


            HttpsURLConnection    httpConnection=  (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            httpConnection.setHostnameVerifier(new AllowAllHostnameVerifier());
            System.out.println(httpConnection.getResponseCode());


        }
        catch (GeneralSecurityException e) {
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please take care to format your source code properly next time, if we can't read it we can't help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An http 403 error usually has nothing to do with the way you connect through HTTPS (unless the site requires client side certificates, not your case). A 403 is a forbidden error code and is probably thrown to prevent robots and other web crawlers from reading their site. Typically they use simple methods like reading the user agent field to stop robots. Java programs all use this user agent by default: Java/version e.g Java/1.8.0_66

Open the page in your browser in debug mode and see what all HTTP headers it's sending, then try to send those same headers from your program.